# I am getting error in gradle file. Using groupId

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-support-library, androidx

Don't know what error I am getting.

Tried many this but unable to resolve this error.

I have changed appcompat versions too. But nothing seems working.

my gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.xxxxxxxxx"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:2.0.0-beta2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:18.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    api 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha08'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:18.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:28.0.0'
}
```

Error

```
Dependencies using groupId `com.android.support` and `androidx.*` can not be combined but found `IdeMavenCoordinates{myGroupId='com.android.support', myArtifactId='documentfile', myVersion='28.0.0', myPacking='aar', myClassifier='null'}` and `IdeMavenCoordinates{myGroupId='androidx.customview', myArtifactId='customview', myVersion='1.0.0', myPacking='aar', myClassifier='null'}` incompatible dependencies
```

manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tool="http://schemas.android.com/apk/distribution"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.example.xxxx">

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"
    android:appComponentFactory="android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory">
    <activity android:name=".RegisterActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity"/>
    <activity android:name=".OtpActivity"></activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Some times I am also getting manifest linking error.
Some times unable to find resources.

Comment: Is androidx enabled in your **gradle.properties** file?
`android.useAndroidX=true`